# ZOD string without spaces validation (no regexp)

Tags: zod

I want to validate the string in ZOD and check that it doesn't contain space. If spaces exist I want to show a custom message. I know that I can do it with regexp but I want to do it another way. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), but I think the approach with regex is a safer bet in general because you can catch all types of whitespace with a more concise syntax.

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const schema = z.string().refine(s => !s.includes(' '), 'No Spaces!');

console.log(schema.parse('cat')); // Fine
console.log(schema.parse('The cat')); // Error
```

Comment: in this case I can't use chain of checks:

z.string().refine(s => !s.includes(' '), 'No Spaces!').regex(/\d+/, 'The prefix should contain only numbers')

wouldn't work

Comment: I think there might be a disconnect between your question and the behavior you are looking for. Do you just want to validate that the string is a string of numbers? Previously you said you were constrained to not using `regex`, but the code you mention above uses them. What specifically are you trying to parse?